# How to pass in a custom parameter to TwiML Bin?

Tags: twilio, twilio-twiml

I have some issues trying to pass a custom parameter to TwiML Bin. See attached pictures. 
Everything works except the paramter.

Any ideas of what I am doing wrong?

Setup:

[image: Pic1]

[image: Pic2]

Answer (score 1):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

[ApplicationSID](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223136607-What-is-an-Application-SID-) is from TwiML [applications](https://www.twilio.com/docs/usage/api/applications) which are containers for a set of URLs and configurations that tell Twilio what to do when one of your Twilio numbers receives a call or SMS message.

If you're using dynamic content from custom HTTP request parameters (ie. *name* in this case), you should take your TwiML bin's URL and pass it the `Name` parameter like this in, for example, Python, to generate a call with the custom parameters:

```
client.calls.create(
    url="your-twiml-bin-url?Name=Jeremy",
    to="your-phone-number",
    from_="your-twilio-phone-number")
```